# how can i automatically increment by 1 a column in my database table based on the number of rows that has using sqlite3 and python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

how can i automatically increment by 1 a column in my database table based on the number of rows that has(see the picture column "ID").[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRa36.jpg)

What i want... is whenever i delete or insert new row in my table, my ID column should auto increment(if it's possible to start from 0). For example when i run a method or i press a button , that column needs to auto-increment again

I need just the statement that does that, thanks a lot!

How i create my table

```
self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, date TEXT,card TEXT,serial_card TEXT,statuscard TEXT)')
```

How i insert in my table

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO cards (date, card, serial_card, statuscard) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, card, SN, status))
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Please try to condense it down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to create your table:

```
self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT,card TEXT,serial_card TEXT,statuscard TEXT)')
```

This will mean that ids of deleted rows can occur again, if you want it so that once an ID has been assigned it can never be assigned again even if the row using it no longer exists in the table, use this line:

```
self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date TEXT,card TEXT,serial_card TEXT,statuscard TEXT)')
```

Comment: are you sure that is the correct sintax? Because i get this error : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error

Comment: I have not put an underscore in `AUTOINCREMENT`, have you added that in when you copied it over?

Comment: Yep, my bad,now it works. But can i specify that autoincrement value to start from 0?

Comment: Something like this? self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT=0, date TEXT,card TEXT,serial_card TEXT,statuscard TEXT)')

Comment: I really need to start increment from 0

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this would be to check if the table is empty and if it is, manually insert a row with an ID of 0.

Comment: Anyway, this is not the solution, because if i have 3 rows introduced, with column id: 1,2,3,  and then i delete first row with the id 1  and then i insert new line, my column ID will look like this 2,3,4 instead of 1,2,3

Comment: If you read my answer you will see how I explained to you that `AUTOINCREMENT` means that IDs will not be reused. If you want deleted IDs to be re-usable, then simply remove the keyword.